Unity Animation Stuck
I'm new to unity and I'm having an issue with my Jump animation. The animation plays when I click space bar, but it freezes after. You can see in the animation window that the transition isn't working. I've been trouble shooting for a few days and have run out of ideas
Playermovement script
eusing System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController2D controller;
    public Animator animator;

    public float runSpeed = 40f;

    float horizontalMove = 0f;
    bool jump = false;

    void Update()
    {
        // Get horizontal input and set speed
        horizontalMove = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * runSpeed;
        animator.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(horizontalMove));

        // Check for jump input
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            jump = true;
            animator.SetBool("IsJumping", true);
            Debug.Log("Jump button pressed. IsJumping set to true.");
        }

        // Debug animator's current state and parameter values
        Debug.Log($"Current Animator State: {animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Player_Idle")}");
        Debug.Log($"IsJumping: {animator.GetBool("IsJumping")}");
    }

    public void OnLanding()
    {
        // Called when the player lands
        animator.SetBool("IsJumping", false);
        Debug.Log("Player landed. IsJumping set to false.");
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // Move the character and reset the jump flag
        controller.Move(horizontalMove * Time.fixedDeltaTime, false, jump);
        jump = false;

        // Debug movement and jumping values
        Debug.Log($"HorizontalMove: {horizontalMove}, Jump: {jump}");
    }
}


Character controller
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class CharacterController2D : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float m_JumpForce = 400f;                          // Amount of force added when the player jumps.
    [Range(0, 1)] [SerializeField] private float m_CrouchSpeed = .36f;          // Amount of maxSpeed applied to crouching movement. 1 = 100%
    [Range(0, .3f)] [SerializeField] private float m_MovementSmoothing = .05f;  // How much to smooth out the movement
    [SerializeField] private bool m_AirControl = false;                         // Whether or not a player can steer while jumping;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask m_WhatIsGround;                          // A mask determining what is ground to the character
    [SerializeField] private Transform m_GroundCheck;                           // A position marking where to check if the player is grounded.
    [SerializeField] private Transform m_CeilingCheck;                          // A position marking where to check for ceilings
    [SerializeField] private Collider2D m_CrouchDisableCollider;                // A collider that will be disabled when crouching

    const float k_GroundedRadius = .2f; // Radius of the overlap circle to determine if grounded
    private bool m_Grounded;            // Whether or not the player is grounded.
    const float k_CeilingRadius = .2f; // Radius of the overlap circle to determine if the player can stand up
    private Rigidbody2D m_Rigidbody2D;
    private bool m_FacingRight = true;  // For determining which way the player is currently facing.
    private Vector3 m_Velocity = Vector3.zero;

    [Header("Events")]
    [Space]

    public UnityEvent OnLandEvent;

    [System.Serializable]
    public class BoolEvent : UnityEvent<bool> { }

    public BoolEvent OnCrouchEvent;
    private bool m_wasCrouching = false;

    private void Awake()
    {
        m_Rigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        if (OnLandEvent == null)
            OnLandEvent = new UnityEvent();

        if (OnCrouchEvent == null)
            OnCrouchEvent = new BoolEvent();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        bool wasGrounded = m_Grounded;
        m_Grounded = false;

        // The player is grounded if a circlecast to the groundcheck position hits anything designated as ground
        // This can be done using layers instead but Sample Assets will not overwrite your project settings.
        Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(m_GroundCheck.position, k_GroundedRadius, m_WhatIsGround);
        for (int i = 0; i < colliders.Length; i++)
        {
            if (colliders[i].gameObject != gameObject)
            {
                m_Grounded = true;
                if (!wasGrounded)
                    OnLandEvent.Invoke();
            }
        }
    }

Here is what I've done so far and my code:

no exit time on transitions
0 seconds transitions duration
any state is for jumping, true and jumping false is for idle and run (also with a speed float which is working)
my event for onlanding only lets me pick a function "string name" from monoscript - don't know if that's relevent


have you tried this code in a new project to find the minimum reproducible code for the issue?

when you say stuck, do you mean it doesnt return to the animation default? (there is no animation window in your post...) so Id question the return path on your current animation branch
